# How to use typeid() on structs

Tags: .net, c++-cli

In a CLI project I have a function that takes an Object^ and has to know which type is stored in the Object. My code works well for classes but how to use it for structs ?

```
using namespace System::Drawing;

void AddObject(Object^% o_Object)
{
    Type^ i_Type = o_Object->GetType();

    if (i_Type == String::typeid) // OK
    {
        ... do something
        return;
    }

    if (i_Type == Rectangle::typeid) // ERROR
    {
        ... do something
        return;
    }
}
```

The compiler says:
error C3083: 'Rectangle': the symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type.

Then I tried:

```
if (i_Type == typeid(Rectangle))
{
    ... do someting
    return;
}
```

Now it tells me:
error C2446: '==' : no conversion from 'const type_info' to 'System::Type ^'

Then I tried:

```
if (typeid(o_Object) == typeid(Rectangle))
{
    ... do someting
    return;
}
```

Now it tells me:
error C3185: 'typeid' : used on managed type 'System::Object ^', use 'System::Object ^::typeid' instead

Then I tried:

```
if (o_Object::typeid == typeid(Rectangle))
{
    ... do someting
    return;
}
```

And it tells me:
error C2653: 'o_Object' : is not a class or namespace name

What can I do ?

Comment: When I use VS2013 and your entire first code block (with the `... do something` lines commented out), I get no error. Make sure you're referencing System.Drawing.dll and try using the full name (`System::Drawing::Rectangle::typeid`) in the if line.

Comment: I suppose you did not #include <windows.h> in your project. I already found the reason. See below.

Comment: No, I did not. I expected you had a naming collision of some sort, but wasn't sure what it would be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason:

The compiler does not take System::Drawing::Rectangle APTHOUGH you write:

```
using namespace System::Drawing;
```

at the top.
The compiler takes the function

```
WINGDIAPI BOOL WINAPI Rectangle(__in HDC hdc, __in int left, __in int top, __in int right, __in int bottom);
```

instead that is defined in WinGdi.h.

I must add:

```
#using <system.drawing.dll>
```

at the top

and addtionally write:

```
if (i_Type == System::Drawing::Rectangle::typeid)
{
     ... do someting
     return;
}
```

to resolve the ambiguity.

It has nothing to do if the typeid is taken from a class or a struct as I thought originally.